Information theoretical interpretation of Free Energy
When exploring the concept of free energy from an information-theoretic perspective, I often come across statements like:
"Free energy measures the degree of surprise an agent experiences when encountering new information."
I am familiar with the concept of free energy in thermodynamics and statistical mechanics:

In thermodynamics, free energy represents the maximum amount of work that can be extracted from a system when the temperature is held constant.
In statistical mechanics, free energy is related to the logarithm of the partition function and tracks the system's progress toward equilibrium.

Additionally, in information theory, I understand that entropy of a probability distribution measures the average number of questions required to determine the outcome of a random draw.
Given this background, can someone clarify how free energy is interpreted from an information-theoretic perspective? Specifically, how does it relate to concepts like surprise, entropy, or prediction in this context?

The question is best answered in the framework of stochastic thermodynamics, where the relationship between thermodynamics and information theory is dealt with explicitly.
Consider a physical system with energy function $E$ coupled to a heat bath at temperature $T$. The nonequilibrium free energy of probability distribution $p$ is defined as
$$\mathcal{F}(p,E)=\mathbb{E}_p[E]-k_B T\, S(p)$$
where $\mathbb{E}$ indicates expectation, $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant, and $S$ is Shannon entropy.
The thermodynamic meaning of the nonequilibrium free energy is as follows. Suppose that you manipulate the energy function $E(t)$ in a time-dependent manner, while interacting with a bath at temperature $T$. The work done over time $t\in[0,T]$ is given by
$W = \int_0^T \mathbb{E}_{p(t)}\big[{\textstyle \frac{d}{dt}} E\big] \,dt$. Suppose that by doing so, you transform a system from initial distribution $p_0$ and energy function $E_0$ to a final distribution $p_T$ and energy function $E_T$. According to the Second Law of Thermodynamics, the minimal work that must be done is given by the increase of nonequilibrium free energy,
$$W \ge \mathcal{F}(p_T,E_T)-\mathcal{F}(p_0,E_0)$$
This bound is achievable in the limit of a very slow process.
Swapping signs gives the maximal work that can be extracted.
Importantly, the nonequilibrium free energy also has an information-theoretic interpretation. Let $p_\mathrm{eq}(x)=e^{-E(x)/k_B T}/Z$ be the equilibrium (Boltzmann) distribution, and let $F_\mathrm{eq}(E)=\mathcal{F}(p_\mathrm{eq},E)$ indicate the equilibrium free energy. It is not hard to show that $\mathcal{F}(p,E)\ge F_\mathrm{eq}(E)$ for any $p$, that is, free energy is minimized in equilibrium. Moreover, the additional nonequilibrium free energy has an information-theoretic expression,
$$\mathcal{F}(p,E)-F_\mathrm{eq}(E)=k_B T \, D(p\Vert p_\mathrm{eq})\ge 0\tag{1}$$
where $D(p\Vert p_\mathrm{eq})$ is the Kullback-Leibler divergence. The left hand side is the maximal work that can be extracted by bringing a distribution $p$ to equilibrium.  For this reason, $k_B T \, D(p\Vert p_\mathrm{eq})$ is sometimes called "availability" or "available work".
Using $(1)$, we may connect free energy to surprise/unlikelihood via large deviations theory. Imagine that you have a population of $N$ independent stochastic particles, each in equilibrium for energy function $E$ and temperature $T$. You measure the empirical  distribution $\hat{p}$, that is the frequencies of different microstates in the population. By Sanov's Theorem, we have
$$\mathrm{Prob}(\hat{p} \approx {p}) \asymp e^{-N D(p\Vert p_\mathrm{eq})} =C e^{-N\mathcal{F}(p,E)/k_B T}\tag{2}$$
where $\asymp$ refers to equality up to sub-exponential factors and $C$ a constant that doesn't depend on $p$. Thus, up to a constant offset, the nonequilibrium free energy is the large deviations rate function. It means that states with a larger $\mathcal{F}$ are exponentially more unlikely to emerge as a fluctuation from equilibrium. In this formal sense, they are more surprising.
In the mathematical literature, the term "free energy" often refers simply to the rate function of empirical occupation statistics, i.e., the exponent in a large deviations principle like $(2)$.
More reading:

Qian, Relative entropy: Free energy associated with equilibrium fluctuations and nonequilibrium deviations, Physical Review E, 2001.
Parrondo, Horowitz, Sagawa, Thermodynamics of information, Nature Physics, 2015.


Thx for your answer! Would you mind checking one of your formulas ( there is a $ symbol to many I think (:- )

One thing troubles me in your explanation as it sounds counter intuitive to me: You say "The left hand side is the minimal work that one can be extracted by bringing a distribution p to equilibrium".  I would have guessed that it is related to the $ \bf{maximal} $ amount of work instead.This is because if the transition happens in finite time there is part of it dissipating as heat into the environment,no?

Apologies for the typos! I fixed the $ and -- as you say -- it is of course the maximal work.

This interpretation is worked out in detail in The free energy principle for action and perception: A mathematical review (2017). There is a good overview on Wikipedia.
The "surprise" is defined mathematically as the negative logarithm $-\log P(S)$ of the probability of some sensory data $S$. It is a measure of how atypical ("how surprising") a sensory input is. To avoid confusion with the psychological notion of surprise, it is common to use the word surprisal. The informational free energy $F_I(S)$ is an upper bound to the surprisal.
The informational free energy is defined in terms of the joint probability $P(E,S)\equiv e^{-H(E,S)}$ of environmental variables $E$ and sensory input $S$ and a model probability $Q(E)$ by
$$F_I(S)=\int dE\, Q(E)H(E,S)+\int dE\, Q(E)\log Q(E).$$
In a thermodynamic interpretation, the first term on the left-hand-side corresponds to the mean energy and the second term to (minus) the entropy.
To prove the inequality $F_I(S)\geq -\log P(S)$ one can rewrite the definition of $F_I$ in terms of the conditional probability $P(E|S)$,
$$F_I(S)=-\log P(S) + \int dE\, Q(E)\log\frac{Q(E)}{P(E|S)}.$$
The second integral on the right-hand-side is positive by Jensen's inequality.

Perhaps worth mentioning that the second integral on the RHS is the relative entropy.

indeed it is, the Kullback–Leibler_divergence

To recap, $F(S) = \mathbb{E}_{E \sim Q} \log \frac{Q(E)}{P(E, S)}$, which is just the relative entropy from $P(\cdot, S)$ to $Q$.
